# Why does floating point become less accurate as the powers of 2 increase?

Tags: floating-point

https://fabiensanglard.net/floating_point_visually_explained/

I was reading this article where the exponent and the mantissa are explained as the window and offset respectively. As the gap between powers of 2 increases, the granularity of the incremental steps that the offset offers will decrease. Is this an intentional design decision?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, almost certainly.  We only have a fixed number of bits, so allowing the most significant bit to represent different powers of two dramatically increases the range of useful values we can represent.

And really, it's a logical behavior.  If you're looking at a number in the trillions, who cares if you are off by .0000001?  An error of that size has no meaningful impact in almost any real situation.

On the other hand, if you're looking at a number in the ten-thousanths, a gap of .0000001 is actually pretty substantial.  We would want to be careful at that granularity to maintain exacting precision.

Comment: When you say "allowing the most significant bit to represent different powers of two", do you mean the 8 bits of the floating point bit vector dedicated to the exponent? I thought the sign bit was the most significant bit.

Comment: @NeelSandell I think it means in the actual number written as binary, not the way it's stored in the computer. You get a power of two, and then a certain number of significant digits after that. So in the number 11010101010 the most-significant bit is 10000000000 and in the number 0.000001011110 the most significant bit is 0.000001

Comment: @NeelSandell I meant the most significant bit of the mantissa.